# MySQL importing large csv

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a large CSV file I am trying to import into MySQL (around 45GB, around 150mil rows, most columns small but one with variable length text, can get up to KBs of size).  I am using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to try and import it but the server always times out my connection before it finishes.  I have tried modifying the global connection timeout variables to fix this, but it already has some hours before it times out.  Is there another way to import a database this large, or am I doing something wrong with this approach?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I am executing this command on Windows 10, with the MySQL command line.  My MySQL version is 8.0.

Comment: What program are you using for this query? mysql command line?

Comment: Yes, I am using the MySQL command line.

Comment: and with your OS information can you update your question, to let people reproduce your problem.

Comment: Obvious suggestion: split the file into smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have handled this in the past is by writing a php script that reads the file and outputs the top 50% into a new file, then deletes those rows. Then perform two load data infiles, one for original and one for the new.

Comment: In conjunction with @Bill-Karwin, this is what I ended up doing, although I am splitting the file into 15 of 10million or less rows.